# Where clause and subqueries in Firebase - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Is there where clause similar feature in Firebase and can we do subqueries to filter results like
1.I would like to get data from to tables (JSON) on the behalf of UID jut like JOIN queries
2.If JOIN is not possible then can I write subqueries like get results from 1 table and filter those result in next query

```
drbooking-3c1a0
 BookInfo
 -KNkxgu4Ax8sjCQ3KwUP
 drid: 
"-KNaaiAVaOnEACTPvGj4"
 time1: 
1000
 time2: 
2000
 uid: 
"z1MEs4wy8TNJmrJHfK7QWIzd57R2"
 -KNq7kYuEiNQFtbVrHXE
 drid: 
"-KNaaiAVaOnEACTPvGj4"
 time1: 
2000
 time2: 
3000
 uid: 
"z1MEs4wy8TNJmrJHfK7QWIzd57R2"
 -KNq7rHK7eO9QrYeTwIt
 drid: 
"-KNaaiAVaOnEACTPvGj4"
 time1: 
4000
 time2: 
6000
 uid: 
"z1MEs4wy8TNJmrJHfK7QWIzd57R2"
 DRInfo
 -KNaaiAVaOnEACTPvGj4
 description: 
"new Reception"
 name: 
"Chitrakoot"
 -KNab6DYSZLH4iM7GbdO
 description: 
"Main DR"
 name: 
"Nalanda"
```

In above structure I would like to get the list of DR those are not booked on a particular time i.e. available list of DR for a time

Comment: yes ... just check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data ... Filter Data

Comment: Yes checked but didn't found fruit full there is some limitation with retrieve data

Comment: what you want to get ... like what condition you want to fulfill with firebase???

Comment: you can check this... may be you get some idea https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html